# Beautiful Soup Web Scraping: CIA WorldFactBook Data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For class, I need to scrape data from https://www.cia.gov/Library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2047.html. I am able to scrape single data points with the following code, specifically for the Country Name and the Highest 10% (which is all I need for this assignment). Using the following code, I can scrape the name "Afghanistan" and the data point for highest 10% "24":

```
f = open('cia.txt', 'w')
import os
os.getcwd()
ciapage = 'https://www.cia.gov/Library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2047.html'
page = urllib2.urlopen(ciapage)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
soup.title
soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"country"})
country = soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"country"})                      
print country[0]
countries = country[0].string
print countries
f.write(countries + "\n")
f.close()

f = open('cia.txt', 'w')
import gettext
percents = soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"fieldData"})
print percents[0].get_text()
print percents[0].contents
for string in percents[0].strings:
    print(repr(string))
for string in percents[0].stripped_strings:
    print(repr(string))
print percents[0].contents[6]
f.write(percents[0].contents[6])
f.close()
```

While all of that runs well, I do not know how to do it for *all* country names and highest 10%s. I have done very little Python, so perhaps using a # with comments on what that line of code means would be very helpful. I need my final product to be a .txt file with comma delineated values (e.g. Afghanistan, 24%).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="https://www.cia.gov/Library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2047.html"
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")

table=soup.find("table", id="fieldListing")
with open('a.txt', 'w') as f:
    for tr in table('tr', id=True):
        l = list(tr.stripped_strings) #['Afghanistan', 'lowest 10%:', '3.8%', 'highest 10%:', '24% (2008)']
        country = l[0]
        highest = l[-1].split()[0]
        f.write(country + ' ' + highest + '\n')
```

out:

```
Afghanistan 24%
Albania 20.5%
Algeria 26.8%
American Samoa NA%
Andorra NA%
Angola 44.7%
Anguilla NA%
Antigua and Barbuda NA%
Argentina 32.3%
Armenia 24.8%
Aruba NA%
Australia 25.4%
Austria 23.5%
Azerbaijan 27.4%
Bahamas, The 22%
Bahrain NA%
Bangladesh 27%
Barbados NA%
```

Comment: It is saying that the "=" on that last line (print(country, highest, file=f)) is a syntax error? When I got rid of it, it says ImportError: No module named requests

Comment: @Sierra Thomander install requests, http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/

Comment: That helped, but it is still giving me the error for the file=f.